# Плохо ли скрывать html элементы при помощи display: none;?

Tags: html, css, seo

Как это влияет на работу сайта и индексацию в поисковых системах?

Answer (score 1):

В принципе, многие подобные методы ранее использовались для сокрытия информации (писали белым шрифтом по белому тексту, дописывая целые полотна ключевых слов в конец страницы).

Если в этих элементах содержится много текста, то по стуку конкурентов могут быть наложены санкции.

Если это какие-то небольшие управляющие элементы -- то можно особо не париться, с тех пор как в сайтостроении всё больше проникает js -- это становится нормальным.